# webpack not ignoring folder

Tags: node.js, webpack

I am using webpack to bundle my files.
I am trying to ignore some folders. But I am getting error in excluded file.
My webpag.config.js file has

```
module: {
        rules: [
            {
            test: /\.js$/,
            include: /js/,
            exclude: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, "js/libs/")
            ],
            use: [{
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }]
        }
    ]
```

I want to exclude all files from lib folder but its not happening. Whats wrong in this code?

Answer (score 0):

```
module: {
        rules: [
            {
            test: /\.js$/,
            include: /js/,
            exclude: [
                './js/libs/'
            ],
            use: [{
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }]
        }
    ]
```

I had same issue. Removing path.resolve solved my problem. you can give a try.

Comment: thanks for your reply @Mushariar. But its not working.
plugins: [
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/libs/)
    ]
this worked for me.

Comment: Sorry didn't help you. Great that found the solution.